# How to get the created FactoryGirl objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users, :dependent => :delete_all

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :users, :through => :company_users

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
```

I use this helper function to create and login:

```
def create_company_admin
  company_user = FactoryGirl.create(:company_user, :has_shopper, :has_company, :admin)
  user = User.first
  login_as user, scope: :user
  company_user
end
```

And this is the actual test

```
feature 'user listing' do
  background do
    company_user = create_company_admin
  end
  scenario 'getting user list' do
    visit '/companies'
    page.has_content? company_user.user.name
  end
end
```

This works until where he calls: company_user.user.name which doesn't seem to exist.  There I get undefined local variable or method `company_user'

This is the factory:

```
factory :company_user, class: CompanyUser do
  authorized true

  trait :admin do
    admin true
  end

  trait :not_admin do
    admin false
  end

  trait :has_shopper do
    association :user, factory: :shopper
  end

  trait :has_company do
    association :company, factory: :company
  end
end
```

Edit:

This is the factory of shopper (which is a kind of user)

```
factory :shopper, class: User do
  username "user"
  email "mail@mai.co"
  password "password1"
  after(:create) do |u|
    u.skip_confirmation!
    u.save!
  end
end
```

How do I get the user, company and company_user in the test?

Answer (score 1):

In your helper you create an `company_user`. But `company_user` belongs to `user` and I dont see you creating a user (you call `user = User.first` after creating `company_user` but that would be `nil`).

I also don't see you creating a company. Create the user in the helper using a factory first, then a company and then the company_user (referencing the user).

You can then access them in your tests with `user = User.first`, `company = Company.first` and `company_user = CompanyUser.first`

Comment: But user seems created because when I follow in firefox I see a logged in user and a company, both are displayed and linked to the user so that's correct.  I edited the question to also include the shopper factory (which is in fact a user).  I tried creating the user in the helper but then I get an error message indicating that the mail address is already used (which also confirms my thinking that the user has already been created with the company_user).

Comment: When I add: user = User.first and company = Company.first under scenario it works.  It that good practice?  What if I have more than one user or company?

Comment: I would say good practice would be to only create the mock objects that you need so that it is easy to reference. You can use `Model.first` if you only created one otherwise pass in a email address (in case of user) to the factory when you create the object and reference it with that in the test. Ok, so your user is created in the shopper factory, so you do not need to create it beforehand (I presume your company factory works the same)

Comment: Once you correctly referenced `company_user = CompanyUser.first` you can reference `company = company_user.company` and `user = company_user.user`